# Is there anyway to create a task from Force.com site?

Tags: salesforce, twilio, apex

I've opened up a visualforce page on sites and on receipt of a private sms ([using twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/salesforce)) I'm trying to create a task.  However everything seems to show this is not possible due to Public Access Settings.  Is there no way to create tasks from a Force.com site?

Answer (score 0):

A VisualForce Page Controller cannot do this on a Force.com Site.  However, if you create a 2nd Apex Class that is Global, your controller can call a method in that class that inserts the Task.